# ckEditor removing <br> when <br> appears directly before <audio>

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor4.x

I'm working on a project where the user should be able to insert a short text and an audio player in an inline ckEditor and save it. Adding the audio works fine, but on saving or refreshing the page the `<br>` directly before `<audio>`  gets removed. Adding any text between the two Elements prevents the `<br>` from being removed.

What I found out so far is, that the `<br>` gets removed by `htmlDataProcessor.toHtml` when the ckEditor is calling `editor.setData`.

What I want to know is why the editor removes the `<br>` and how I can avoid this.

Below I added a snippet which shows the same behaviour as the editor in my project.

```js
CKEDITOR.inline('editor1', {
  enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
  allowedContent: true
});
```

```css
div {
  border-style: solid;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.11.2/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
  CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
</script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor1">Text <br> <audio controls></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if possible why dont you put audio inside a div?

Comment: @Harshit We would like to avoid adding html to fix such problems, because the content can be edited on different devices and we don't want html which is only necessary for one divice to appear in all devices. But Thank you anyway. I will consider this if there is no other option.

Comment: have you tried <pre></pre> instead of div?

Comment: I don't see how this would make difference. Maybe I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

add `extraAllowedContent:'audio;*(*);*{*}'`  it will allow you insert audio tag in your editor .

```js
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;


CKEDITOR.inline('editor1', {
  enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
  allowedContent: true,
  extraAllowedContent:'audio;*(*);*{*}'
});
```

```css
div {
  border-style: solid;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.11.2/ckeditor.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true" id="editor1">Text <br> <audio controls></div>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my Problem. Adding audio to the editor is not the Problem. In fact in my snippet the audio is added correctly. The Problem is, that the br before audio is removed.

Comment: @L.Janofske , so you want to add <br/> tag in your content ?

Comment: The <br/> Tag is already in the editor. See:
`<div contenteditable="true" id="editor1">Text <br> <audio controls></div>`
But it gets removed by the ckEditor.